# use sed or awk to remove string from particular column where the start and end of the string are known

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, osx

my file contains lines like this:

```
1 10241 rs960927773 POS=10241;VP=0x05;GINFO=DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
```

I would like to remove everything from column 4 beginning with POS and ending ;GINFO=

I think this may work: `sed -e 's/POS=.*;GINFO=//‘ file > new_file`

If it’s ok, how do I direct it to column 4 specifically?

Answer (score 0):

To address the 4th column directly use the following **`awk`** approarch:

```
awk '{ sub(/^POS.*GINFO=/, "", $4) }1' file > new_file
```

- `$4` - points to the 4th field
- `sub(/^POS.*GINFO=/, "", $4)` - substitutes a substring given by pattern `/^POS.*GINFO=` within 4th field

Answer (score 0):

if columns you mean and known separated with space, then you could do as following:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^ ]* ){3})POS=.*;GINFO=/\1/' infile
```

This `^(([^ ]* ){3})` matches start from begging of the line `^` for anything `*` not a space `[^ ]` until a first space seen and repeat this for maximum `{3}` times; Parentheses make this match as a grouping match with back-reference of `\1` which later we revert it back in replacement part `s/pattern/replace/`.

This `(...)POS=.*;GINFO=` also matches `POS=` followed by anything `.*` till `;GINFO` seen and will remove from the output.

For the given below sample data:

```
1 10241 POS=rs960927773 POS=10241;VP=0x05;GINFO=DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
1 POS=10241 rs960927773 POS=10241;VP=0x05;GINFO=DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
POS=1 10241 rs960927773 POS=10241;VP=0x05;GINFO=DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
```

Will return a result:

```
1 10241 POS=rs960927773 DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
1 POS=10241 rs960927773 DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
POS=1 10241 rs960927773 DDX11L1:100287102;R5;ASP
```

The POSIXly version could be:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* \)\([^ ]* \)\([^ ]* \)POS=.*;GINFO=/\1\2\3/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

In POSIXly sed we may do this way:

```
sed -ne '
   #place a markholder at the beginning of the 4th field
   s/[^[:blank:]][[:blank:]]\{1,\}/&\
/3

   # perform the sub on the 4th field
   s/\nPOS=.*;GINFO=//p
'  input_file
```